# Numpy, multiply array with scalar

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ufunc

Is it possible to use ufuncs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html
In order to map function to array (1D and / or 2D) and scalar
If not what would be my way to achieve this?
For example:

```
a_1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
a_2 = np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
b = 2.0
```

Expected result:

```
a_1 * b = array([2.0, 4.0, 6.0]);  
a_2 * b = array([[2., 4.], [6., 8.]])
```

I`m using python 2.7 if it is relevant to an issue.

Comment: You used the tag `numpy` but you are using lists. Use numpy arrays and it will work

Comment: Just transform to `np.arrays`: `np.array(a_1)*b` and `np.array(a_2)*b`

Comment: It should work for nested lists too, if they are not jagged (as in your example)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can multiply numpy arrays by scalars and it just works.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3]) * 2
array([2, 4, 6])
>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) * 2
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12]])
```

This is also a very fast and efficient operation. With your example:

```
>>> a_1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> a_2 = np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
>>> b = 2.0
>>> a_1 * b
array([2., 4., 6.])
>>> a_2 * b
array([[2., 4.],
       [6., 8.]])
```

Comment: does this work for any of ufuncs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-broadcasting) may help.

Answer (score 15):

Using [.multiply()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html)  (**ufunc multiply**)

```
a_1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
a_2 = np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
b = 2.0 

np.multiply(a_1,b)
# array([2., 4., 6.])
np.multiply(a_2,b)
# array([[2., 4.],[6., 8.]])
```