# Change point size in seaborn FacetGrid scatterplot

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot, facet-grid

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  row="sex")
# g.map(sns.scatterplot, "total_bill", "tip", s="size")
```

works nicely.  But uncomment that last line in the hopes of varying the dot size in the scatterplots, and you get an error: `s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y`.

Based on [ValueError: s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131029/valueerror-s-must-be-a-scalar-or-the-same-size-as-x-and-y), I speculate that it's because the dataframe is filtered for each facet plot, but the "Size" column of the dataframe is being passed along without being filtered down to only the values in scope for a particular facet.

Darned if I know what to do about it, though.  Anyone got a fix?